# (Python) Use Tkinter to show a plot in an independent window (Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I referred to the following useful tutorial video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8exB6Ly3nx0

And I used his codes (see 6:28); however, the graph was plotted under the cell instead of the independent window.

How to overcome this?  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Did you try running `%matplotlib` at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that does what you want. Jupyter-notebooks don't use the tk backend for plotting by default so you have to explicitly instruct matplotlib to use it.

That can either be done as shown below, or using the notebook magic `%matplotlib` as metioned by @acw1668 in the comments.

I personally find that not practical, and there are other solution to use interactive plots inside a notebook, as e.g. jupyter-lab [widgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html) that I would rather refer you to.

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

root = Tk()
root.title("dsafsdff")
root.geometry("400x200")

def graph():
    f, a = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    house_prices = np.random.normal(0., 1, 1000)
    a.hist(house_prices)
    plt.show()

my_button = Button(root, text="afdgfsdgf", command=graph)
my_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use %matplotlib tk in the first line to render graphics in an independent window managed by tkinter.